# Creating centered inline cell in text cell

Tags: manipulate, cdf-format, cells, gui-construction

The cell
[image]
corresponds to the textual form

```
Cell[TextData[{
   "The ", StyleBox["average rate of change", FontWeight->"Bold"],
   " in ",
   Cell[BoxData[FormBox["f", TraditionalForm]]],
   " on the interval ",
   Cell[BoxData[FormBox[
      RowBox[{"[", RowBox[{"a", ",", RowBox[{"a", "+", "h"}]}], "]"}], TraditionalForm]]],
   " is the slope of the corresponding secant line: \n",
   Cell[BoxData[FormBox[GridBox[{
       {GridBox[{{
           RowBox[{SubscriptBox["m", "sec"], "=", FractionBox[
             RowBox[{RowBox[{"f", "(", RowBox[{"a", "+", "h"}], ")"}], "-", 
              RowBox[{"f", "(", "a", ")"}]}], "h"]}]}
       },
       GridBoxAlignment->{"Columns" -> {{"="}}}]}},
      GridBoxItemSize->{"Columns" -> {{
           Scaled[0.96]}}}], TraditionalForm]]],
   "\nThe ", StyleBox["instantaneous rate of change", FontWeight->"Bold"],
   " in ",
   Cell[BoxData[FormBox["f", TraditionalForm]]],
   " at ",
   Cell[BoxData[FormBox["a", TraditionalForm]]],
   " is "
  }], "Definition",
   CellChangeTimes->{{3.454944654993936*^9, 3.45494474976772*^9}, {
    3.4549518777111692`*^9, 3.454951884742343*^9}, {
    3.460806271054368*^9, 3.4608062731390657`*^9}, {
    3.478189589239235*^9, 3.478189591304613*^9}, {3.487447061963195*^9, 
    3.487447061963235*^9}}]
```

I can't figure out how to enter this in the Mathematica user interface. It seems as though the displayed equation on the second line is an inline cell that is aligned using `GridBox`, but I don't see how to create that effect.

Comment: Are you sure it was created in the front end? Maybe it was imported from TeX, MathML or something. Or it was modified manually, adding `GridBoxItemSize` option there.

Comment: Well, that's always possible. I doubt it was modified manually, but it could have been imported from TeX. So you think there's no way of doing this in the front end?

Comment: Maybe there is, I just tried to do this and didn't find anything.

Comment: Use the palette `Writing Assistant` available in the `Palettes` menu. See the options under `Math Cells` drop-down menu in the `Writing and Formatting` section of the palette.

Comment: @kguler Yes, that kind of works. It adds a new cell, which can then be merged with the text cells above and/or below and gives me pretty much what I want. However, it does seem to use inline styling rather than display styling (for example, limits on sums are to the right of the summation sign rather than above and below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out, after lots of poking around, that the fact that the cell is `inline` is not really the relevant thing. What is relevant is that each stylesheet has a property, `LimitsPositioningTokens`, that specifies which symbols should use the off-to-the-side limits positioning by default. For the `Text` style, that list includes all the usual things, including `lim`, $\Sigma$, and $\Pi$. Removing those symbols from the list produces the positioning that I wanted.

Additionally, it turns out that the portion of the book quoted in the original question was not imported --- it was all hand entered. There is a useful video [here](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?channel=88&video=776) that describes the process of putting the interactive book together. It is only 30 minutes long, so it does not go into great detail, but there was a lot of useful information there if you are planning any kind of real doc-writing project in Mathematica.

Answer (score 6):

This is different but you may find it useful. The second line will be evaluated in place code with panel, just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> to create an inline cell and type:

> [image]

select this and evaluate in place with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

> [image]

Comment: The code can also be `Pane[HoldForm[\[Placeholder]], Full, Alignment -> Center]`, which can then be edited, in case the expression to be centered cannot be put into *Mathematica* code. (+1)

Answer (score 3):

The nested single-element GridBoxes make it likely that this format was generated by code.  In fact, the inline cell expression matches exactly that generated by the *Equal Symbol Aligned Math Cell* from the *Writing Assistant* palette (in V9, at least):

[image: screenshot showing the Writing Assistant palette]

Comment: Yes, I noticed that as well. What I don't understand is that the palette element inserts an inline cell, so that constructs are built with inline visuals (for example, the limits on a sum are below and to the side, rather than above and below, the summation sign). And if I try to convert this to an equation style, either manually by editing the text in the notebook file or visually in the front end, the equal sign alignment is lost.

I find document construction with Mathematica to be really difficult and not well documented. Is there a good discussion somewhere of how to do this?

Comment: Oops, I somehow missed the comments to this effect under the question.  I'm afraid I am not aware of a good resource for this.  Judging from the source that ships with Mathematica, it would seem that WRI frequently writes box language directly to obtain finicky formatting -- bypassing not only the UI but also functions like `Grid`, etc.