# How to center a graphic in its output cell

Tags: notebooks, formatting

Say I have produced a single graphic ouput, perhaps a plot.  Instead of displaying left-aligned in the notebook, I would like it to display in the center of the output cell.  I would like it to stay centered if I change the magnification.  I would like it to be centered when I export to PDF.

Possible?

Comment: It is not very intuitive but you select the output cell and then select _Format | Text Alignment | Align at Center_. This will align the cells contents to centre as long as you do not delete the output cell.  You can re-evaluate the expression and the output will stay centred.

Comment: @Edmund. You should post your comment as an answer. Short as it is, it is a complete and useful answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use `Pane`/`Framed` etc. + `Full` width + `Alignment`:

```
Pane[
 Graphics @ Disk[],
 Full, 
 Alignment -> Center
]
```

related: [46028](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46028/5478)

Answer (score 9):

It is not very intuitive but you select the output cell and then select *Format | Text Alignment | Align at Center*. This will align the cells contents to centre as long as you do not delete the output cell. You can re-evaluate the expression and the output will stay centred.

Answer (score 5):

To get programmatically the same effect that [Edmund](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/19542/edmund) points out, one can explicitly construct the output cell:

```
CellPrint[
 ExpressionCell[
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, -7, 7}],
  "Output",
  TextAlignment -> Center
  ]
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

To center a text cell from an equation, I use

```
CellPrint[
Cell[BoxData[
 PaneBox[HoldForm[1 + 1 = 2] // ToBoxes, Alignment -> Center, 
ImageSize -> Full]], "Text"]]
```