# Center the output of Plot, Plot3D, etc

Tags: textalignment

I am well aware of how to manually center the contents of an output cell (**Format>TextAlignment>AlignCenter**), and how to force *all* output cells to be aligned in the center (as shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/231341/how-to-automatically-center-the-alignment-of-all-output-cells)).  I also know how to use CellPrint and related functions to force an output cell to be centered (as shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92926/how-to-center-a-graphic-in-its-output-cell)).  But I don't want to type such a wrapper every time I want to simply Plot.

I need something just a bit different:  I'd like the output of every plot (Plot, Plot3D, DiscretePlot, ...) to be centered in the output cell, but not center the output of other functions, for instance from calculations.  (All this is for presentation slides, where centered figures look best.)

I thought the right approach would be to set an Option -> (TextAlignment ->Center) for Plots in an initialization cell, but TextAlignment is not an option proper for plots.

How do I set some option to center all plot outputs, but not the outputs of other functions?

Comment: Maybe `$Post = Replace[#, g : _Graphics | _Graphics3D :> Style[g, TextAlignment -> Center]] &;` but I hate using `$Post`.

Comment: Oh that works fine!  I'll put it in the initialization cell.  Thanks for teaching me about $Post.  If you post your code as an answer, I'll accept it.