# How to add a Checkbox into a text cell?

Tags: notebooks, text-formatting

Before working in my code I wrote tests on a *textcell* . I want to add a *checkbox* at the end of each sentence to track my progress. So, I will checkbox if the program pass.

How to add a Checkbox into a text cell?

Comment: Like that: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46028/5478

Comment: It works! Thanks @Kuba